# Conditions under which the torsion subgroup of an abelian group is a direct summand.

Tags: group-theory

Hi: Let $T$ be the torsion-subgroup of an abelian group $G$. If $T$ is the direct sum of a divisible group and a bounded group, then T is a direct summand of $G$.

The author says "This follows easily from 4.1.3 and 4.3.8".

4.1.3 A divisible subgroup is a direct summand.

4.3.8 A pure bounded subgroup of an abelian group is a direct summand.

Suppose $T=0\oplus B$ where $B$ is bounded. Of course $0$, the trivial subgroup of $G$, is divisible. Then $T$ is bounded. How do I apply 4.3.8 to prove $T$ is a direct summand of $G$?

Note: bounded group = group of bounded order.

Comment: Which author (and text) are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your example, $T$ is bounded, so to apply 4.3.8, it suffices to show $T$ is pure.

Let $t\in T$, and suppose $n{\,\mid\,}t$ in $G$.

We want to show $n{\,\mid\,}t$ in $T$.

Since $n{\,\mid\,}t$ in $G$, we have $t=ng$ for some  $g\in G$.

Since $t\in T$, we have $mt=0$ for some positive integer $m$, so
$$(mn)g=m(ng)=mt=0$$
hence $g\in T$

Thus $n{\,\mid\,}t$ in $T$, so $T$ is pure.

Now consider the general case . . .

Thus suppose $T=D\,{\large{\oplus}}B$, where $D$ is divisible and $B$ is bounded.

Our goal is to show that $T$ is a direct summand of $G$.

Since $D$ is divisible, it follows  by 4.1.3 that $G=D\,{\large{\oplus}}H$ for some $H\le G$.

Let $S$ be the torsion subgroup of $H$.

Since $B$ is bounded, we have $mB=0$ for some positive integer $m$.

Let $s\in S$.

Clearly $s\in T$ so $s=d+b$, where $d\in D$ and $b\in B$.$\;$Then
\begin{align*}
&
s=d+b\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
ms=md+mb\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
ms=md\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
ms\in D\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
ms=0\;\;\;\text{[since $ms\in S\subseteq H$ and $D\cap H=0$]}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus $mS=0$ so $S$ is bounded.

Since $S$ is the torsion subgroup of $H$, it follows (as in the first part of this post) that $S$ is pure in $H$, hence since $S$ is bounded, it follows by 4.3.8 that $S$ is a direct summand of $H$.

Thus we have $H=S\,{\large{\oplus}}K$ for some $K\le H$, hence we can rewrite $G=D\,{\large{\oplus}}H$ as $G=D\,{\large{\oplus}}S\,{\large{\oplus}}K$.

Claim $T=D\,{\large{\oplus}}S$.

The inclusion $D\,{\large{\oplus}}S\subseteq T$ is clear.

For the reverse inclusion, let $t\in T$.

Since $G=D\,{\large{\oplus}}S\,{\large{\oplus}}K$, we have $t=d+s+k$, where $d\in D$, $s\in S$, and $k\in K$.

Then from $k=t-d-s$, it follows that $k$ has finite order, hence $k=0$.

Thus $t=d+s\in D\,{\large{\oplus}}S$, which yields $T\subseteq D\,{\large{\oplus}}S$.

Hence $T=D\,{\large{\oplus}}S$, as claimed.

Then we can rewrite $G=D\,{\large{\oplus}}S\,{\large{\oplus}}K$ as $S=T\,{\large{\oplus}}K$, so $T$ is a direct summand of $G$ as was to be shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your proof shows that the torsion subgroup of 4g4

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your proof shows that the torsion subgroup of an abelian group is always pure! I didn't know this. Then to prove the statement let $T=D\oplus B$ with $D$ divisible and $B$ bounded. I must only show that $T$ is bounded. How do I do it?

Comment: It's enough to show that $D$ is bounded knowing it is divisible and torsion. But, again, how?

Comment: @stf91: A nonzero divisible group $D$ is never bounded. Proof: Let $m$ be a positive integer such that $mD=0$ and let $x\in D$. Since $D$ is divisible we have $x=my$ for some $y\in D$, but from $mD=0$ we get $my=0$ hence $x=0$. Thus $D=0$.

Comment: @stf91: Is the problem from a book? If so, which one?

Comment: @stf91: I've updated my answer to address the general question.

Comment: It is proposition 4.3.9 (page 110) in A Course in the Theory of Groups, 2nd edition, by Derek Robinson.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why is $k=0$?

Comment: @stf91: $k$ is in $H$ but not in $S{\,\setminus}\{0\}$, and $S$ is the torsion subgroup of $H$, hence if $k$ has finite order, it must be equal to zero.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think the statement in the OP is an easy consequence of 4.1.3 and 4.3.8. It is anything but easy.

Comment: Easy for the author, presumably.